# how create class to manage sessions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have a class and want to create,delete and edit sessions on it
but have error:"object null reference" when i want to add data to my session.
if i remove inheritance from controller how can i handle it?

my data is string value like "name"
why this syntax:  Session[name]=value; works fine in controller but not works in my class and give me null reference error?

```
public class StateManager : Controller
    {
       public  void RemoveFromApplication(string name)
     {
         Session.Remove(name);
     }
    public  void AddToApplication(string name, object value)
    { 
       //value like "name"
        Session[name]=value;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably doesn't work because the controller isn't instantiated the same way by MVC, when it doesn't matches the current route.

You could instead create a static class like this:

```
public static class SessionManager
{
  public static void RemoveFromApplication(string name)
  {
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(name);
  }

  public static void AddToApplication(string name, object value)
  {
    HttpContext.Current.Session[name] = value;
  }
}
```

You could also pass the session in the the methods as a parameter:

```
public static class SessionManager
{
  public static void RemoveFromApplication(string name, HttpSessionStateBase session)
  {
    session.Remove(name);
  }

  public static void AddToApplication(string name, object value, HttpSessionStateBase session)
  {
    session[name] = value;
  }
}
```

The class and methods doesn't need to be static, if you don't want it to be.